# Counting instances of a value in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of times a value shows up in a sorted list.
I know I can just use the count method but why does the following code not work?

```
lst = []
a = ['polka dot sock\n', 'polka dot sock\n', 'polka dot sock\n', 'red sock\n', 'superhero shirt\n', 'torn jeans\n', 'white shirt\n', 'white shirt\n']
for x in a:
     c = 0
     while x in a:
          c += 1
          a.remove(x)
     lst.append((a, c)) 
print lst
```

The code works for everything except 'red sock\n' and 'torn jeans\n'. Why is that? Is it an indexing issue?

Comment: In short, in place of `for x in a:`, you can try `for x in a[:]:`

Comment: Is there any reason you're appending `(a, c)` to `lst` instead of `(x,c)`, or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Yes, this is an indexing issue. The for loop continues to increment, and is applied over the modified list.

### Long:

If you add:

```
    print x
    print a
```

after your `a` declaration, you get the following output:

```
    ['polka dot sock\n', 'polka dot sock\n', 'polka dot sock\n', 'red sock\n', 'superhero shirt\n', 'torn jeans\n', 'white shirt\n', 'white shirt\n']
    polka dot sock

    ['red sock\n', 'superhero shirt\n', 'torn jeans\n', 'white shirt\n', 'white shirt\n']
    superhero shirt

    ['red sock\n', 'torn jeans\n', 'white shirt\n', 'white shirt\n']
    white shirt
```

You can see that `polka dot sock` is `a[0]` of the original list, `superhero shirt` is `a[1]` of the modified list, and `white shirt` is `a[2]` of the again modified list. Due to this, your 'red shirt' and 'torn jeans' are getting skipped, since they're now `a[0]` and `a[1]` of your modified lists.